# Freeze the first 5 columns in each of the 3 P-tables and need to do horizontal scroll simultaneously in p tables

Tags: angular, p-table

I have three individuals p-tables and they have three horizontal scroll bars within the p-tables they have frozen columns so i need to achieve
Simultaneously horizontal scrolling for example if I move horizontal scroll bar of one table other two tables horizontal scroll also move without
breaking frozen columns how I can achieve within angular ng prime?

I have tried many scenario here i am using angular prime ng and new on this not able to achieve

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.